# How to get a ViewModel from other Activity?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel, android-workmanager

I'am creating a Login Activity on my App.

I have a `Viewmodel` + `LiveData` + `DataBingind` to update a TextView and display info about the progress of all background work when a user try to login.

```
lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity) as LoginActivityBinding
    binding.viewModel = loginViewModel
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    ...
}
```

All background work are done by `Workers`

```
val loginWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LoginWorker>().setInputData(dataBuilder.build()).addTag("LOGIN").build()

val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
                workManager.beginUniqueWork("LOGIN", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, loginWork)
                        .enqueue()
```

I can acces and update the `ViewModel` from the LoginActivty observing the progress of the `Worker`:

```
val statusLogeo: LiveData<WorkStatus> = workManager.getStatusById(loginWork.id)
                statusLogeo.observe(this, Observer {
                    if (it != null && it.state == State.FAILED)...

                    if (it != null && it.state == State.SUCCEEDED)...


                })
```

But I only can acces to the data inside the Worker when the procces Failed `State.FAILED` or Succeded `State.SUCCEEDED`...

So for example if all the work in that `Worker` last 10 seconds, I can't update the `ViewModel` from my Login Activy until all the work be done... But if I acces to the same `ViewModel` from the Worker Activity I can update during that procces.

How can I get a ViewModel from other Activity?

How can I get the same instance of the LoginWorkerViewModel (created in the LoginActivity and setup for dataBinding) from the Worker activity?

Comment: If your LoginWorkerViewModel extends AndroidViewModel then it will be the same instance for all users of.